# How to iterate multiple checkboxes with *ngFor using Form Array([]) and data from API

Tags: angular, checkbox, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have dynamic `checkbox` that get data from API, following is `html` file

**html :**

```
<pre>{{summons|json}}</pre>
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <label formArrayName="summons" *ngFor="let summon of summons.items; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
      <span>
   {{summon.respCode}}    
      </span>
  </label>

  <br>
  <button [disabled]="!form.valid">submit</button>
</form>
```

it will create multiple `checkbox` based on `items` in `test.json`,(if items consist of 2 `items` it will produce 2 `checkbox`) I had succesfully iterate all data in html file but I cant produce `checkbox` and display the data, I call data from API which in my `ts file`

**ts file :**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  form: FormGroup;
  summons = [];

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private inquiryService: InquiryService) {

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      summons: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.getSummons();
  }

  getSummons() {
    this.inquiryService.getData().subscribe(summons => {
      this.summons = summons;
      this.addCheckboxes();
      console.log(summons);
    });
  }

   addCheckboxes() {
    const control = new FormControl();
    const formArray = this.form.controls.summons as FormArray;
    formArray.push(control);
  }
}
```

I also had created stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ckpqs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for this questions, also I had follow this [tutorial](https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular), I need to solve how to iterate `checkbox` based on API in `FormArray` and it should display the data, need advice and guide

**expected output :**
[image: 2 checkbox]

Comment: `summons.items` looks wrong for me. shouldn't it be just `summons`? You will also always push only 1 formcontrol since you never take the actual length of summonds into account when calling àddCheckboxes`.

Comment: can you explain more, and how I want to know actual length of summons when calling addCheckboxes

Comment: summons is an array which you can iterate directly. Simply pass summons to your addCheckboxes function and use it to receive the actual length

Comment: can you please show me how to do this ? @MoxxiManagam

Answer (score 0):

I've amended quite a bit of your code, please see here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljvzea?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

There were quite a few problems, you were calling items without going through data.items first. Also you need to have formArrayName in a container before the *ngFor loop. I also notice that your entire data is a big array which could really just be a normal object.

I didn't see a boolean value in your data so it leaves me to wonder as to what you are relying upon to do a checkbox?

Comment: Hi Andrew, based on your stackblitz demo, I managed to solve my prob, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unrxbp?file=src%2Fapp%2Finquiry-response%2Finquiry-response.component.ts..do you have any comment ?

Comment: @hafizi I think you need to clean up your stackblitz example because I can't get into the page in question.